# tmux: enable mouse only when shift pressed

Tags: tmux, mouse

I've tried to `set -g mouse on`, and it works pretty well, but standard mouse behaviour (select, copy & paste) is disabled. But, it enables if I press "Shift" button, and while I hold it, I can select, copy & paste text from/to terminal. Can I inverse this behaviour? I want to use mouse inside tmux (for example to select panes or resize them) only with shift pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long: The behavior is terminal-dependent...

The terminals that you would use `tmux` on hard-code their behavior to match the behavior of **`xterm`**.

While `xterm` provides a way to assign different actions to different mouse/button/modifier combinations (see [Default Key Bindings](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings)), it makes assumptions about the use of the <kbd>shift</kbd> key as well.  The `translations` resource is flexible in some respects, but does not (aside from the `keymap` feature introduced in X11R4) provide for changing the translations back/forth as one starts and stops mouse-mode.