# Middle-click paste in Screen with Mousetrack Enabled

Tags: gnu-screen, mouse, clipboard

I am using GNU Screen and I added `mousetrack on` to my `~/.screenrc` so that I could select a window pane by clicking on it.

Unfortunately, since I enabled that setting, I can no longer use middle-click paste in any screen windows. Is there a way to enable mousetrack and still have middle-click paste?

I am using GNU Screen v4.03.01 in GNOME Terminal v3.18.3 on Ubuntu Desktop (Unity) v16.04.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310912/tmux-enable-mouse-only-when-shift-pressed) is similar, but related to tmux. My question is about GNU Screen.

Comment: Press the "shift" key while doing the paste.  It's frequently answered...

Comment: @ThomasDickey thank you, shift worked; however, i don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked to because screen and tmux are entirely different pieces of software.

Comment: That's irrelevant, since the terminal emulator is what determines the behavior.

Comment: I had a question on this, what would to add in the ~/.screenrc to avoid the pain of holding shift button all the time??

Comment: @Invictus it looks like you would need to configure your terminal, not screen. the terminal is what requires holding "shift". as far as i could find, this isn't configurable in most terminals and it's probably required for an important reason that i don't understand.

Comment: @Invictus as best as i understand it, if a console application wants to use the mouse (as happens when enabling `mousetrack on` in screen), that application gets full control of the behavior of the mouse and the terminal emulator then requires you to hold shift if you want to use the mouse in the way the terminal usually uses the mouse (such as middle-click pasting).

Comment: I'm using screen 4.06.02 on Cygwin and Thomas Dickey's comment to press the `shift` key worked for me :)